# Access an image to display in a pdf header (yii2, mpdf)

Tags: image, header, yii2, mpdf

I work with yii2 and mpdf. 
I have an action in a controller that creates a pdf file.
I am trying to display an image in the pdf header. The image is located in project/web/images.

I use the following code:

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div><img src="' . baseUrl . '/web/images/image1.png"></div>');
```

There is no error when executing the code, but I can't get the image to the header.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it `baseUrl`? Not `$baseUrl`?

Comment: I had a similar problem recently ... you have solved by putting the right variable or the problem continues to stay even with the correct path?

Comment: No the problem stays, even though I am supposed to use the right path.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing worked:

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div><img src="images/image1.png"></div>');
```

Thank you!